# Pip overwrites package with local version specifier

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, versioning

I want to install a specific version of PyTorch (inside a Dockerfile) to handle modern GPUs: `1.8.1+cu111`. Please note the local version identifier. I then install (both via pip) a library that requests `torch>=1.8.1` as a dependency. For some reason, this uninstalls my `1.8.1+cu111` and replaces it with vanilla `1.10.0`, despite the custom version with "local version specifier" should be taken as valid as [PEP 0440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) says (`...local version labels MUST be ignored entirely when checking...`) and it's what is happening normally, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808433/python-package-version-vs-version-with-local-version-label) or even for me when I try to re-install PyTorch by hand:

```
pip install "torch>=1.8.1"
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.8.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (1.8.1+cu111)
```

But no, when I install my library, I get this:

```
...
Collecting torch>=1.8.1
  Using cached torch-1.10.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (881.9 MB)
...
Installing collected packages: torch,...
  Attempting uninstall: torch
    Found existing installation: torch 1.8.1+cu111
    Uninstalling torch-1.8.1+cu111:
      Successfully uninstalled torch-1.8.1+cu111
```

How can I make it keep the pre-installed `1.8.1+cu111`?

Answer (score 0):

In the [PEP040](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#inclusive-ordered-comparison),  you have above:

```
When multiple candidate versions match a version specifier, the preferred version SHOULD be the latest version as determined by the consistent ordering defined by the standard Version scheme. Whether or not pre-releases are considered as candidate versions SHOULD be handled as described in Handling of pre-releases.
```

I think this because you are using an inclusive specifier [where local version identifiers are NOT permitted](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#inclusive-ordered-comparison)

Can you specify the exact version with `pip install "torch==1.8.1+cu111"` ? Maybe only 1.8.1 works.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I installed PyTorch using the exact specifier: `pip install torch==1.8.1+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`, the problem is that when I install another library afterwards, which has torch>=1.8.1 as a dep, it's overwritten.

Comment: OK. I got it. 
Do you try to reverse the order of installation ? First the second lib and second torch ? 

or directly trying to solve the depencies directly (*mylib* is the library you want to install)

``pip install mylib torch==1.8.1+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`` 

If you give the exact lib, it would be easier.

Comment: When I installed torch afterwards, it overwrote it, because it was a specific version. But because it's inside a Dockerfile, I want to have the dependency (torch) earlier on, so that it doesn't get redownloaded and reinstalled every time I make a release. HOWEVER, luckily the situation is that I have two libraries with the one depending on torch updating not very often (torch<-L1<-L2), so I can do `pip install -f /local/folder L1 -f https://download.pytorch... torch==1.8.1+cu111` and then separately later `pip install -f /local/folder L2` and it does NOT overwrite torch, but no idea why!